# pushing a zip file to GitHub repository

Tags: github

I am pretty new to GitHub and I have lots of problems working with that.  I have created a repository in my GitHub account and then a folder named "Data Set" in the repository.  Now i want to *push a zip file to this  folder*.  what should I do? i have Git Bash on my windows too.

Comment: `git status` ... `git add *` `git commit -m "initial"` `git push`(login/ensure ssh connected/trusted/use (latest) git bash!;)

Comment: It is not a good practice to have zip files in a git repository, but in your case you have to open git bash on the Data Set filder. Then `git add .` `git commit -m "first commit"` `git push`